# which of the following are necessarily true ?..

Tags: real-analysis

Let $ f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function satisfying $f(x+y) =f(x)f(y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, and $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0 }f(x) =1$$ Which of the following are necessarily true?

$(1)$ $f$ is strictly increasing .

$(2)$ $f$  is either  constant or bounded

$(3)$ $f(rx) =f(x)^r$ for every $ r \in \mathbb{Q}$

$(4)$ $f(x)\ge 0$ for all  $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Here  $f(x) = 1 $ that mean option $2$ is the only correct option.

Am I right?

Comment: Option $2$ is for sure wrong since $\exp$ is not bounded and not constant.

Comment: oohhh i  didn't  notice that @TheGeekGreek

Comment: Option 1 is wrong because we can take $e^{-x}$ and still satisfy the hypothesis.

Comment: Option $4$ must be true because of $f(2x)=f(x)^2\ge 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$

Comment: @Peter im not getting   which  function u take ?? i mean$ f(3x) = f(x)^3\le 0$  then  option 4 become false

Comment: I just applied the condition $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ for the case $x=y$

Comment: thanks u @Peter i got its  and what about option 3?

Comment: For positive integers $n$, you can extend my equality via induction to $f(nx)=f(x)^n$ quite easily. Not quite sure yet about the negative and the non-integer case.

Comment: Another idea however could be useful. If $f(0)=0$, then for every $y\in \mathbb R$ we have $f(y)=f(0)\cdot f(y)=0$, so we have the function $f(x)\equiv 0$. So, we can assume $f(0)=a>0$ and I think we can show that we must have $f(x)=a^x$, but I do not know exactly yet how. If we have shown this, option $3$ is obviously true.

Comment: @Peter plug in $mx/n$ for $x$ in $f(nx)=f(x)^n$

Comment: Sorry, $f(0)=a$ is wrong, it must be $f(1)=a$, but the argument is similar.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I thought about that as well. Should work

Comment: It is a rather classical fact that any function $g$ which satisfies $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$ and is bounded on some interval must be of the form $g(x)=ax$. By taking logarithms, it implies that the only functions $f$ in the problem are $f(x)=e^{ax}$

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Then everyting is clear. Formulate this as an answer and I will upvote it.

Comment: @Nehagupta Also note $$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} f(x+\epsilon)=\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} f(x)\cdot f(\epsilon)=f(x)$$ for all $x,\epsilon \in \mathbb R$, so $f$ is continous, so we have $f(0)=1$ and because of $$f(0)=f(-x+x)=f(-x)\cdot f(x)$$ we get $$f(-x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$$

Comment: @Peter,,, thanks  u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been answered from basic principles in the comments but (as a bit of an overkill) it may be worth adding that any function $g$ which satisfies $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$ and satisfies some mild regularity condition, like being bounded on some interval, must be of the form $g(x)=ax$. This is discussed in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation. By taking logs it follows that the only functions $f$ in the question are of the form $f(x)=e^{ax}$.

Comment: Superb and short solution (+1)